# Standard Error Bars in wrong position on my graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, errorbar

I am trying to graph my data in R for my research project and for some reason on the three graphs I have created my error bars look like this. They are all at the bottom of the bars rather than in the correct spot on the top.

[image]

Here is my coding for that specific graph:

```r
ggplot(Epiphyte_Biomass,aes(x=Treatment, y=Epiphyte.Biomass,fill=Treatment))+
    geom_bar(stat="Identity")+
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mean(Epiphyte.Biomass)-sd(Epiphyte.Biomass), 
                      ymax=mean(Epiphyte.Biomass)+ sd(Epiphyte.Biomass)), 
   width=0.2)+
   theme_classic()
```

Comment: a [mcve] would be very helpful!

Answer (score 3):

When you computed the mean and sd, ggplot didn't automatically subdivide the data by group, so I think you got the *overall* mean and SD (the mean looks low, but perhaps you have fewer data points in the "NC+N" treatment?)

`ggplot2` has some built-in convenience wrappers for functions from the `Hmisc` package that compute different kinds of ranges, but ±1 SD bars are not included.  Try

```r
msd <- function(y) {
   my <- mean(y, na.rm = TRUE)
   sy <- sd(y, na.rm = TRUE)
   data.frame(y = my, ymin = my - sy, ymax = my + sy)
}
## and use this in place of `geom_errorbar()`:
+ stat_summary(fun.data = msd, geom = "errorbar")
```

Here is an example using `mtcars`:

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(cyl, mpg, fill = factor(cyl))) +
    stat_summary(geom = "bar", fun = mean) +
    stat_summary(geom = "errorbar", fun.data = msd)
```

The point is that this way `ggplot` does all the mean and SD calculations per treatment for you, on the fly, rather than your having to do them separately ...

It looks as though your data set may already have computed the mean of epiphyte biomass per treatment, in which case your SD calculations will be messed up anyway (they will be the SDs *across* treatment means rather than the within-treatment SDs)

Comment: Im sorry I'm really new to this but Im actually really confused looking at this. Can you simplify or explain? I dont know where my variables would go or anything

Answer (score 2):

I think the error is in -+sd(Epiphyte.Biomass)... You have to calculate sd for each treatment separately. In your case, sd is the same for both!

Comment: What do I do once I've calculated them separately?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example with the mtcars dataset.
Just take your variables and put them in.

I really appreciate Ben Bolkers answer. It is not trivial to set the errorbars at least if you are not doing it every day.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plyr)

# function
data_summary <- function(data, varname, groupnames){
    require(plyr)
    summary_func <- function(x, col){
        c(mean = mean(x[[col]], na.rm=TRUE),
          sd = sd(x[[col]], na.rm=TRUE))
    }
    data_sum<-ddply(data, groupnames, .fun=summary_func,
                    varname)
    data_sum <- rename(data_sum, c("mean" = varname))
    return(data_sum)
}


# definition of variables
df <- data_summary(mtcars, varname="mpg", 
                    groupnames=c("cyl"))

# plot
ggplot(df, aes(x=factor(cyl), y=mpg, fill=factor(cyl))) + 
    geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", 
             position=position_dodge()) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=mpg-sd, ymax=mpg+sd), width=.2,
                  position=position_dodge(.9))
```

[image]

Comment: I figured out the standard deviation and the standard error value. My question is how do I put it into R because its 0.7527062 for my NC+N and 0.0649061 for my NC. So how do I tell R to put different error bars for these different standard error values for each treatment.